# Vue Youtube teaser playing in the thumnail to the right

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am having a video site. Where users can upload YouTube videos. The teasers of the videos should be playing on top of the same thumbnail. However they are playing on the thumbnail to the right behind the next thumbnail. and the last one is playing outside the container. Below is my code

[image]

**kYoutube.vue**

```
<script>
const getLogger = require('webpack-log');
const log = getLogger({ name: 'vue-khal' });
import VueYoutube from 'vue-youtube';

export default {
  extends: VueYoutube,
  methods : {
    playerStateChange(e) {
      log.info ("PSC on " + e.data);
      if (e.data !== null && e.data !== -1) {
        this.$emit(this.events[e.data], e.target)
      }
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

**PreVideo.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="vid-cont">
    <div class="thumb-place">
      <PreImage :post="post" :sizes="sizes" @loaded="handleLoad"></PreImage>
    </div>
    <label v-if="post.proof_img == null">
      <div @mouseover="startVideo" @click="emitClick" v-bind:class="thumbZ">
        <img ref="pimage" :src="post.post_image.image"
             :srcset="post.post_image.thumbs"
             :sizes="sizes" style="object-fit: cover;"/>
      <img v-if="playImg" class="pre-play-button" :src="playImg" :key="playImg"/>
      </div>
      <div v-if="iReady" class="player-cont" :key="iReady">
        <youtube :video-id="videoId" ref="youtube"
                 @playing="playing" @ended="ended" @cued="ended" @paused="paused"
                 :width="width" :height="height"
                 :player-vars="playerVars" :fitParent="true"></youtube>
      </div>
      <div class="player-cont player-trans" @mouseout="pausePreview" @click="emitClick">
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</template>
<script>

import PreImage from './PreImage';
const getLogger = require('webpack-log');
const log = getLogger({ name: 'vue-khal' });

export default {
  name: 'Video',
  props: [
    'post',
    'sizes',
  ],
  components: {
    PreImage
    //VueYoutube
  },
  data() {
    return {
      'first': this.post.post_image,
      'videoId': this.post.video_id,
      'width': 0,
      'height': 0,
      'iReady': false,
      'playerVars': {
        'autoplay': 0,
        'rel': 0,
        'enablejsapi': 1,
        'controls': 0,
        'disablekb': 1,
        'fs': 0,
        'modestbranding': 1,
        'cc_load_policy': 0,
        'origin': document.location.origin
      },
      'playImg': null,
      'pReload': false,
      'rates': [],
      'preview': false,
      'duration': 0,
      'count': 1,
      'userState': -1,
      'numSkips': 3,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    thumbZ: function() {
      return {
        'thumb-cont': true,
        'thumb-top': (this.userState < 3)
      };
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    var that = this;
    this.api.map_prom.then(() => {
      that.playImg = that.api.mkstatic("youtube_red.png");
      that.pReload = !that.pReload;
    });
  },

  updated() {
    var that = this;
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      if (that.iReady && that.userState < 0) {
        that.$refs.youtube.player.mute().then(() => {
          that.toState(0);
          that.$refs.youtube.player.playVideo().then(() => {
          });
        });
      }
    });
  },
  methods: {
    emitClick() {
      this.$emit("clicked");
    },
    pausePreview() {
      this.toState(1);
      this.$refs.youtube.player.stopVideo();
    },
    delayedPause() {
      var that = this;
      this.toState(2);
      that.$refs.youtube.player.pauseVideo().then(function(){
        //log.info ("Paused ?? ");
        that.$refs.youtube.player.getPlayerState();/*.then(data => {
          //log.info ("STATE is " + data);
        });*/
      });
    },
    jump() {
      if (this.userState <= 2)
        return;
      var that = this;
      var ct = parseInt(this.duration * this.count / this.numSkips);
      //log.info ("Jump call " + that.count);
      if (this.count <= this.numSkips) {
        this.$refs.youtube.player.seekTo(ct, true).then(function(){
          //that.$refs.youtube.player.getPlayerState().then(data => {
            //log.info ("STATE " + data + " Jumped to " + ct + " at " + (new Date()).getTime());
            that.count++;
            that.$refs.youtube.player.pauseVideo().then(function(){
              /*that.$refs.youtube.player.playVideo().then(function(){
                //setTimeout(that.jump.bind(that), 10000);
              });*/
            });
          //});
        });
      }
      else {
        this.$refs.youtube.player.stopVideo();
      }
    },
    toState(state) {
      //log.info ("From " + this.userState + " to " + state);
      this.userState = state;
    },
    /* If you are paused, play */
    paused() {
      switch (this.userState) {
        case 2:
        //log.info ("Paused, playback " + this.count);
        if (this.count <= this.numSkips) {
          this.toState(3);
          this.$refs.youtube.player.playVideo();
        }
        else {
          this.$refs.youtube.player.stopVideo();
        }
        break;
      case 3:
      case 4:
        var that = this;
        that.$refs.youtube.player.playVideo().then(function(){
          setTimeout(that.jump.bind(that), 2000);
        });
        break;
      }
    },
    /* If you're playing, pause in a sec */
    playing() {
      //log.info ("Playing called " + this.userState);
      switch (this.userState) {
      case 0:
        var that = this;
        that.$refs.youtube.player.pauseVideo().then(() => {
          if (!that.duration) {
            that.$refs.youtube.player.mute().then(() => {
              that.$refs.youtube.player.getDuration().then(data => {
                that.duration = data;
                //log.info ("Duration " + that.duration);
                that.$refs.youtube.player.getAvailablePlaybackRates().then (data => {
                  //log.info ("Data is " + data);
                  that.rates = data;
                  let rate = Math.max.apply(null, that.rates);
                  that.$refs.youtube.player.setPlaybackRate(rate).then(() => {
                    //log.info ("Suggested is " + rate);
                    this.toState(1);
                  });
                });
              });
            });
          }
          else {
            this.toState(1);
          }
        })
        break;
      case 3:
        this.toState(4);
        setTimeout(this.jump.bind(that), 2000);
      }
    },
    startVideo() {
      if (this.userState == 1) {
        this.toState(2);
        this.paused();
      }
    },
    handleLoad(ev, post) {
      this.post = post;
      if (!this.$parent.modalOpen) {
        //this.post.post_image = post_image;
        this.height = ev.target.clientHeight;
        this.width = ev.target.clientWidth;
        log.info ("PREvid handle load** " + this.width);
        this.iReady = true;
      }
    },
    ended() {
      //log.info ("ENDED indeed");
      this.count = 1;
      this.toState(0);
      this.$refs.youtube.player.playVideo();
    },
  }
}
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

**PostList.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
  <div ref="me" :class="postListClass" :style="`top: -${scrollOff}px`">
    <Loading :loading="loading == 'L'" :loaderror="loading =='E'"></Loading>
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="row in posts" :key="row">
          <td v-for="post in row" :key="post">
            <div class="post-grid" v-if="post.post_image != null"  ref="postgrid" :key="post">
              <PreVideo v-if="post.video_id" :post="post" :sizes="sizes" @clicked="selectPost(post.pk)">
              </PreVideo>
              <PreVideoFile v-else-if="post.video_file" :post="post" :sizes="sizes" @clicked="selectPost(post.pk)">
              </PreVideoFile>
              <PreImage v-else :post="post" :sizes="sizes" @clicked="selectPost(post.pk)">
              </PreImage>
              <div class="post-title" @click="selectPost(post.pk)">
                <KTruncate :inhtml="post.title" :stripped="post.title" :nomore="true" length="30"></KTruncate>
              </div>
              <div class="post-user">
                by <a :href="post.user.profile.url">{{post.user.full_name}}</a>
              </div>
              <div class="post-synopsis">
                <KTruncate :inhtml="post.message" :stripped="post.stripped" :nomore="true" length="60">
                </KTruncate>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="way-container" v-if="nextPageURL !== '' || loading == 'E'">
      <Loading :loading="'L'" :key="loading" :loaderror="loading == 'E'" class="way-div" v-waypoint="{ active: true, callback: onWaypoint, options: intersectionOptions }" id="More">
      </Loading>
    </div>
  </div>
  <PostModal v-if="selectedPost > 0" ref="modal" :pk="selectedPost"
             @closed="onHideDetail" @modalOut="onModalOut" :key="selectedPost"></PostModal>
</div>
</template>

<script>
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import Loading from './Loading';
import PostModal from './PostModal';
import KTruncate from './KTruncate';
import PreVideo from  './PreVideo';
import PreVideoFile from  './PreVideoFile';
import PreImage from  './PreImage';

const getLogger = require('webpack-log');
const log = getLogger({ name: 'vue-khal' });

const getOffsetTop = element => {
  let offsetTop = 0;
  while(element) {
    offsetTop += element.offsetTop;
    element = element.offsetParent;
  }
  return offsetTop;
}


export default {
  name: 'PostList',
  components: {
    Loading,
    PostModal,
    KTruncate,
    PreVideo,
    PreVideoFile,
    PreImage
  },
  data() {
    return {
      scrollOff: 0,
      origTop: null,
      postListClass: "post-scroll",
      selectedPost:0,
      posts: [],
      numberOfPages:0,
      pages : [],
      numberOfPosts:0,
      loading: null, //false,

      nextPageURL:'',
      previousPageURL:'',
      size:'',
      winWidth: window.innerWidth,
      intersectionOptions: {
        root: null,
        //rootMargin: '0px 0px 0px 0px',
        threshold: [0.25, 0.75] // [0.25, 0.75] if you want a 25% offset!
      },
      divisor: 4,
      modalOpen: false,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    pk: function (newpk, oldpk) {
      log.info ("Change from " + oldpk + " to " + newpk);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onWaypoint ({ going, direction }) {
      if (!this.loading) {
        // going: in, out
        // direction: top, right, bottom, left
        if (going === this.$waypointMap.GOING_IN &&
            direction === this.$waypointMap.DIRECTION_TOP &&
            this.nextPageURL != '') {
          log.info ("Waypoint " + this.nextPageURL + " ??");
          this.loading = 'L'; //true;
          this.api.getItemsByURL(this.nextPageURL).then((page) => {
            this.posts = this.posts.concat(this.breakupPosts(page.data));// this.posts = page.data;
            this.nextPageURL = page.nextlink;
            this.previousPageURL = page.prevlink;
            this.loading = null; //false;
          }).catch (err => {
            log.info ("Waypoint err " + err.code + " " + err.message);
            this.loading = 'E';
          });
        }
      }
    },

    breakupPosts(data) {
      let posts = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        let row = parseInt(i / this.divisor);
        if (row >= posts.length)
          posts.push([]);
        posts[parseInt(i / this.divisor)].push(data[i]);
      }
      return posts;
      /*this.posts = page.data.reduce((acc, k) => {
          acc[parseInt(k/3)].push(page.data[k])
          return acc;
          }, {});*/
    },

    getPosts(){
      if (this.origTop == null) {
        this.origTop = getOffsetTop(this.$refs.me);
      }
      this.loading = 'L'; //true;
      this.api.getFeedPosts().then((page) => {
        this.setPage(page);
    this.numberOfPosts = page.count;
    this.numberOfPages = page.numpages;
    if(this.numberOfPages) {
          for(var i = 1 ; i <= this.numberOfPages ; i++) {
            const link = `/api/posts/?page=${i}`;
            this.pages.push({pageNumber: i , link: link})
          }
        }
      }).catch (err => {
        log.info ("Final status* " + err.code + " " + err.message);
        this.loading = 'E';
      });
    },
    getPage(link){
      this.loading = 'L'; //true;
      this.api.getItemsByURL(link).then((page) => {
        this.setPage(page);
      }).catch (err => {
        log.info ("GetPage err " + err.code + " " + err.message);
        this.loading = 'E';
      });
    },
    getNextPage(){
      this.loading = 'L'; // true;
      this.api.getItemsByURL(this.nextPageURL).then((page) => {
        this.setPage(page);
      }).catch (err => {
        log.info ("GetNextPage err " + err.code + " " + err.message);
        this.loading = 'E';
      });
    },
    setPage(page) {
    this.posts = this.breakupPosts(page.data);//this.posts = page.data;
    this.nextPageURL = page.nextlink;
    this.previousPageURL = page.prevlink;
        this.sizes = page.sizes;
    this.loading = null; //false;
    },
    getPreviousPage(){
      this.loading = 'L'; // true;
      this.api.getItemsByURL(this.previousPageURL).then((page) => {
        this.setPage(page);
      }).catch (err => {
        log.info ("Get Prev err " + err.code + " " + err.message);
        this.loading = 'E';
      });

    },
    onHideDetail() {
      this.postListClass = "post-scroll";
      let sides = document.getElementsByClassName ("tofix");
      for (let i = 0; i < sides.length; i++) {
        sides[i].classList.remove ("postbg-fixed");
      }
      log.info ("On hide detail " + this.selectedPost);
      this.selectedPost = 0;
    },
    onModalOut() {
      setTimeout(this.scroller.bind(this), 100);
    },

    scroller() {
      document.documentElement.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop = this.scrollOff + this.origTop; //document.body.scrollTop = this.scrollOff;
      this.scrollOff = 0;
    },
    selectPost(post) {
      log.info ("Select post called " + post );
      this.selectedPost = post;
      this.modalOpen = true;
      this.scrollOff = (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop) - this.origTop;
      this.postListClass = "post-fixed";
      let sides = document.querySelectorAll ("tofix");
      for (let i = 0; i < sides.length; i++) {
        sides[i].classList.add ("postbg-fixed");
      }
      log.info ("Select post done " + this.selectedPost);
    },
    getDivisor() {
      let u600 = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 600px)');
      let u900 = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 900px)');
      this.divisor = u600.matches ? (u900.matches ? 4 : 3) : 2;
    },
    handleResize() {
      if (window.innerWidth != this.winWidth) {
        this.winWidth = window.innerWidth;
        this.getDivisor();
        this.posts = this.breakupPosts(this.posts.flat());
      }
    },
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  },
  updated() {
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getPosts();
    this.getDivisor();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
  },
}
</script>
<style scoped>
.table>tbody>tr>td {
    border-top: transparent;
}

.post-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
}

#More {
    -height: 100px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: From what you're showing you're only missing `left: 0` in your CSS. Since this needs inspection for a definitive answer, you should provide a *runnable* [mcve]. Use codesandbox.io if you need a multi-file node-like editor. Without one, all you'll get are wild guesses which are, most times, a waste of time on everyone's part.

Comment: Great! Just to make it clear: there are two main reasons your question hasn't been answered when you first posted it: 1) you posted too much code (you should only post the minimal needed to repro); 2) your code is not runnable. While this is not always a problem, when dealing with CSS issues one needs to see it working in order to determine exactly what applies to the element and how it could be fixed.

Comment: @tao where should I add `left: 0` PreVideo.vue or PostList.vue If this works that will be amazing

Comment: From looking at the markup I guess it should go on `.player-cont` but without inspecting it I can't be sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227197/discussion-between-samir-tendulkar-and-tao).

Comment: This seems to be just a positioning issue. try playing with `position: absolute`, `position: relative`, `left`, etc. Inspect the rendered HTML with your Browser's Dev Tools and play with the actual element you want to position along with it's parent containers/`div`'s.